# AWS API Gateway: How to insert logs of each API call with output?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have a REST API created in AWS API Gateway with backend implemented using AWS Lambda functions. There are nearly 50 API calls and underlying lambda functions. Now I want to store each of the API call url, params and request body along with error/response to some log table in our database. Is there any way I can accomplish this without modifying the code of each and every lambda function for the same. I have a custom authorizer lambda function on most of the API calls. So, I thought about writing the logic to insert to DB in that function. But the problem is that I cannot get access to the output in the authorizer function. Is there any other way where I can access the input and output both ?

Answer (score 0):

The custom authorizer function is intended to make authorization decisions only and is not supported for this use-case.

Please see response in [AWS API Gateway: Is it possible to add source IP address in each API method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984135/aws-api-gateway-is-it-possible-to-add-source-ip-address-in-each-api-method)

Thanks,
Ryan