# AWS API Gateway: Is it possible to add source IP address in each API method?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have created an API using AWS API Gateway. Now I want to log each of the request on each method of each resource. Also, I need the source IP address of the client accessing the route. How can I accomplish this without writing custom code in the API functions ?

Answer (score 3):

The default CloudWatch logs for your API should include all headers, including the X-Forwarded-For header which will contain the source IP address. (See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-stage-settings.html)

If you need custom logging you will need to implement this in your Lambda functions. You could take advantage of something like Apex or Serverless and write some automation to manage your Lambda functions and share duplicate code.

Comment: I am using `$context.identity.sourceIp` in my integration request mapping template. However, it is working fine when I test from POSTMAN but not working correctly when tested from the front end of the website. Any idea ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working correctly"? Are you calling your API from a website using the javascript SDK?

Comment: it worked. The Content-Type was set to `multipart/form-data`. Setting it to `application/json` got it working